# How would I extract list of licensed users from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have been asked to try and extract a list of all licensed users from Microsoft Dynamics 2013 via the API and I had a look through the documentation but couldn't find anything specifically about licenses.

Is this possible and could someone point me in the direction of some examples and/or documentation?

(NB. This is on premises, not Office 365)

Comment: I'm not an expert in Licenses, but in an on prem scenario, you should have an X number of licenses and be able to activate more users then the licenses you have let's say X+n all the users are active, but you are breaching the license conditions. In an online scenario instead you should be able to check the active users, but all the license part is managed via the office 365 portal.

Answer (score 2):

The system user record has a license type field which determines the type of license they have - specifically CalType.

[User and team entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328485.aspx)

> Specifies the user’s license type.
>
> - Administrative – The user has administrative user rights.
> - Device Full – The user who is using the device running Microsoft    Dynamics CRM has both read and write access.
> - Device Limited – The user who is using the device running Microsoft    Dynamics CRM has only read access.
> - Full – The user has both read and write access.
> - Limited – The user has only read access.

So out of the box I believe you can just create an advanced find to see this information. For SDK access either perform a retrieve multiple query.